# Is it impossible to override a parent bean without an alias?

Tags: java, spring, overriding, javabeans, alias

I have a bean ***parent*** in ***module1-spring.xml***

```
<bean id="parent" class="sample.Parent" />
```

It is NOT aliased.

If I create another bean ***child*** in ***module2-spring.xml*** to override the parent

```
<alias name="child" alias="parent"/>
<bean id="child" class="sample.Child" parent="parent"/>
```

Then the server startup would fail with the error-

> BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name
>   'child' defined in class path resource [module2-spring.xml]: Could not
>   resolve parent bean definition 'parent'.

Is it impossible to override a bean that is not aliased?

Comment: I recall answering the same question before... No this wouldn't work... The child now is the parent, so it would reference himself.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes. I asked that one as well. This is more general.